# Looping through passed parameters in Capybara

Tags: capybara, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I would like to create a Capybara method for reading the contents of a table, that takes a variable number of parameters and iterates through the parameters.

Here is the method I have:

```
Then /^I should see a table record with "(.*?)", "(.*?)", "(.*?)"$/ do |invisible, name, address, phone|
  rows = page.all(".table-bordered tr")
  expect(rows.any? { |record| record.has_content? name }).to be_true
  rows.each do |record|
    if record.has_content? name
      expect(record.has_content? address).to be_true
      expect(record.has_content? phone).to be_true
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using the same CSS table structure to create tables with much larger numbers of columns elsewhere in the program.  So whether the table has 3 columns or 12, I'd like to be able to use the same method so I don't write awkward code.

How can I assign a variable number of parameters and loop through each parameter in Capybara?

Answer (score 0):

```
def assert_my_table(name, *row_data)
  # It will be much faster than looping through all rows
  row = page.find(:xpath, "//*[@class='table-bordered']//tr[./td='#{name}']")

  # retrive row contents only once (again, it will be faster than retrieving it again for each of the columns you want to assert)
  row_text = row.text

  row_data.each do |text|
    expect(row_text).to include(text)
  end
end
assert_my_table(name, address, phone)
```